# Gather element of a list based on their head

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering, head

I have list of the form

`{y[-1], y[0], w'[1], y'[0], w'''[-1], z''[-1]}`

and I would like to gather the elements together based on their heads to have

`{{y[-1], y[0], y'[0]}, {w'[1], w'''[-1]}, {z''[-1]}}`

My attempt so far has been to use

`GatherBy[{y[-1], y[0], w'[1], y'[0], w'''[-1], z''[-1]}, FreeQ[Head[#], y] &]`

which yields

`{{y[-1], y[0], y'[0]}, {w'[1], w'''[-1], z''[-1]}}`

I feel likes it's almost there and all it needs is to apply a similar function again on the subparts of the list above looking instead for heads that contain `w` and then `z`. But isn't there a more direct way to do what I want as this might become very cumbersome and slow when there are more than just three variables to check for ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always start by looking at the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html):

```
{y[-1], y[0], w'[1], y'[0], w'''[-1], z''[-1]} // FullForm
```

> ```
> List[
>  y[-1],
>  y[0],
>  Derivative[1][w][1],
>  Derivative[1][y][0],
>  Derivative[3][w][-1], 
>  Derivative[2][z][-1]
> ]
> ```

```
myHead[Derivative[_][h_][_]] := h
myHead[h_[___]] := h

GatherBy[{y[-1], y[0], w'[1], y'[0], w'''[-1], z''[-1]}, myHead]
```

[image]

You can of course add other definitions to `myHead` to declare certain parts of other expressions as the "head" for the purpose of this gathering.

Comment: That's wizardry. Thanks very much

Comment: @jrekier thanks :D